# Drupal - optimal WYSIWYG editor with image browsing support

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ckeditor, wysiwyg, drupal-modules

Currently using CKEditor + IMCE.

- http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor + http://ckeditor.com/
- http://drupal.org/project/imce

**Are there better alternatives for a Drupal rich-text editor with image upload support?**

To set it up, I add the modules, enable them, add the CKEditor source, configure the Default CKEditor profile to not load unless I tell it to, disable security filters until it loads, and enable the Drupal - Full toolbar version. This gives me all the CKEditor features and flexibility, image and flash upload support via IMCE.

I have tried CKFinder, but I rarely use it on client projects (non-free usage licences). Other modules are a pain to configure and may sometimes break the interface or content (especially around full HTML or PHP inputs).

*Update 1: Added a small bounty, looking for more answers.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having trouble with the CKEditor module over and over again, I switched to http://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg , which encapsulates the JS of multiple WYSIWYG Editors in a generic way (by using input filters, which somehow feels like The Right Thing to me). 
Add http://www.drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg - the WYSIWYG IMCE bridge module, and it works almost exactly as CKEditor.module and IMCE would. A plus: It works with other editors, too, just download and install the editor JS code per the instructions.

Comment: I use the wysiwyg module + http://ckeditor.com on all my client production sites, seems to work great.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you http://drupal.org/project/whizzywig it is light, full featured and natively includes an image browser (have a look at the comparison table).

Comment: Thumbs up for the rather interesting suggestion, I can't consider it a better alternative, but it sure is a light and easy to install.

Answer (score 1):

I did a comparison on our blog a while ago, looking at some solutions.

Currently I'm sticking with wyswiwyg + imce + tinymce + imce_wysiwyg. 
BUT I don't think it's the perfect solution. However in Drupal 6, we don't really have a central image library, this will be a lot better in Drupal 7.

I would recommend checking this module out:
http://drupal.org/project/nrembrowser
It integrates with CKEeditor and might be the way to go.